# Set table name to variable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, java, jdbc

I am trying to set the tablename dynamically in a postgresql query executed through a jdbc connection. Here is my code:

```
PreparedStatement query1 = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        //String xmlData = null;


                conn = postgresVoyateDBConnection();
                query1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ? " +
                                             "WHERE id=? ");


                query1.setString(1, tableName);
                query1.setInt(2, id);

                ResultSet rs1 = query1.executeQuery();
```

However. when I run this, I get an error like this:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

From my quick research I figured out it is not possible to place table names dynamically like this. Are there any workarounds? What does this $1 mean?

Comment: `$1` refers to the first question mark (positional parameter).  You have to use dynamic SQL to set the table name form a variable.

Comment: @dezso can you give an example on how to put table name as variable in dynamic sql please?

Comment: You will have to concatenate your query string.  To avoid SQL injection, you will have to validate the table name.  If you know the possible table names beforehand, it is easy to match the name against the known list before building the query string.  Then you can use the `prepareStatement` method as usual, just binding and later passing only one variable.